Models have a weird dotted-like texture when viewing in Material Preview & Rendered, how do I fix this issue?
I recently got Blender v4.2.1 and already I'm starting to have a render issue when viewing in Material Preview and Rendered on EEVEE Render engine but when I go into Cycles Engine, it looks normal only in Rendered viewport. I decided to check if it was something with the nodes I use by loading a new  General and turns out it has nothing to do with the nodes I use as the white dot texture issue still persisted, even for a model that doesn't have nodes. And it's definitely not any textures I give models as the cube doesn't have any textures added either.
Is there a way I could fix this issue so I could see the renders without any weird texture bug?


That's almost certainly an issue with your graphics drivers. Check that you have the latest version of the drivers installed and that your machine is compatible with Blender 4. Requirements & Compatibility.
